# Add credit to get_custom_header in alt

Tags: custom-header, accessibility

Been hunting for a while and I can't figure out how to use `get_custom_header` to get the alt text associated with the media file, so that I can add photo credits to the headers on my site. Am I missing something?

Code to add header image is:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

The `get_custom_header` function doesn't seem to have a way to pull in the alt text.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you've done so we can tell you what you might have missed ;)

Comment: Added a little more detail if that helps.

Comment: Interested to know whether the answer helped...I'm not certain that it's valid, and would like to know if this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for the `alt=""` attribute on the custom header `<img>` tag …

```
alt="<?php  
$attachment_id = get_custom_header()->attachment_id;
$alt = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
if ( count( $alt ) ) echo $alt;
?>" />
```

… and then just edit the media attachment and add the alt text.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
get_custom_header()->description
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The array returned from `get_custom_header` doesn't include a `description` key